# Как получить введеное значение textarea vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<textarea class="form-control" v-model="users.name" @blur="event => editName(event, 'name')" rows="3"></textarea>

editName(event, key) {
      console.log(key);
      console.log('Значение поля textarea');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте `event.target.value`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: {}
  },
  methods: {
    editName(event, key) {
      console.log('Значение поля textarea =', event.target.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea class="form-control" v-model="users.name" @blur="event => editName(event, 'name')" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, значение получено